# Mysql group concat with averages of exchanges

Tags: mysql, concatenation

I have a list of exchanges and there rate and the date, it is updated every day,

example ->

```
usd - 135 - 26/02/2013
Yen - 230 - 26/02/2013
GBP - 200 - 26/02/2013

usd - 136 - 25/02/2013
Yen - 230 - 25/02/2013
GBP - 205 - 25/02/2013
```

I have a query that group-con them up and 
the query is this ->

```
SELECT Curr, Src, GROUP_CONCAT(Rate, '|', Feeddate 
ORDER BY feeddate ASC SEPARATOR ',' ) AS RateCal 
FROM rates
```

so it looks like this ->

```
usd - 135 | 26/02/2013, 136 | 25/02/2013
Yen - 230 | 26/02/2013, 230 | 25/02/2013
GBP - 200 | 26/02/2013, 206 | 25/02/2013
```

But I also have a query to get me averages of each exchanges for each month 
which is this ->

```
SELECT  Curr, DATE_FORMAT(Feeddate,'%Y-%M') AS 'Year', AVG(`Rate`) as 'Rate'
FROM rates,
```

but what i would like to have now is to have the monthly averages of each exchange group concat like above

Comment: What do you like to have?

Comment: but what i would like to have now is to have the monthly averages of each exchange group concat like above

Comment: can you show your desired result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could it be this that you are looking for? Using your sample data and adding some for month of `March`.

[SQL DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/25e72/3)

```
select curr, monthname(date), avg(rate)
from rates
group by curr, monthname(Date);

| CURR | MONTHNAME(DATE) | AVG(RATE) |
--------------------------------------
|  GBP |        February |     202.5 |
|  GBP |           March |       207 |
|  usd |        February |     135.5 |
|  usd |           March |       136 |
|  Yen |        February |       230 |
|  Yen |           March |     232.5 |
```

It looks too simple to be true. So please comment.

### AS per OP's comment:

[SQL DEMO 2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/25e72/13)

```
select x.curr, 
GROUP_CONCAT(x.avgr, '|', x.mondate) as Months_Averages
from (select curr, monthname(date) mondate,
avg(rate) avgr
from rates
group by curr, monthname(date)
)x
group by x.curr;

| CURR |                      MONTHS_AVERAGES  |
------------------------------------------------
|  GBP |    202.5000| February,207.0000| March |
|  usd |    135.5000| February,136.0000| March |
|  Yen |    230.0000| February,232.5000| March |
```

Comment: If you want rates to be `group_concat` by exchange, then you need to show us how Exchange data is in the main table... :)

Comment: What I wanted was to some how connect my 2 queries, so it sould look like this GBP - 205|February, 204|January, ..., so what I get is GBP averages for each month and then groupconcat it, so i will have value for each month.

Comment: @user2115506 please take a look at the updated code. That seems to match what you need, as it group_concats each month, and each month's average for each currency.

Comment: Sweet, that works the way I want, thank you very much, I been trying many methods, and i am still new to this.

Comment: Glad it helped. If your question is answered, then you may accept this as the answer. As it helps community as well. No pressure, please see how to accept an answer. Thanks.